# Drag and Drop( ctrl+drag) Problems in Xcode

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

There are two places within Xcode (version 13.3) where I can't drag and drop anymore.

1. Trying to move a file to a Group.  I have tried just clicking and dragging, control-click, option-click, command-click, none work.  Instead of dragging the file, the cursor just moves without the selected/highlighted file and highlights whatever file or group it is hovering over.
2. Trying to drag a button to a View Controller to make a connection.  Instead, a popup window appears with three rows, each with corresponding icon, two lines each (title and object type): View Controller, View, Button.  (I can't figure out how to capture that screen since I am already holding the control key and mouse button (track pad) but here is a photo.

**Update:**. All works fine when using a mouse but these two problems always exist when using the trackpad.  I did discover that by pressing the Escape key, I can perform the control-drag (but not move files).  I have played with the trackpad settings but have not yet been able to figure out how to get rid of that window that appears.

[image]

This popup appears whether I am holding the control, option, or command key.

Answer (score 0):

What xcode version are you using, just tried

#1 is working as expected on my xcode13.0

#2 seems to be working for me too.. [image]

Comment: I am using 13.3.  I have restarted Xcode and rebooted the computer without luck.  I wonder if it's a computer setting rather than an Xcode setting?

Comment: I've also tried it in different projects, same problem.